# Could not open my mobile provisioning profile in XCode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode

**Background:**

Trying to upload my application to the iOS App store. I have a valid developer account and I am running on xCode 6.4. I have successfully been able to make a certificate and then get a distribution provision file.

**Problem:**

I have downloaded my provision profile and supposedly when I double tap the provision file, my xCode is supposed to pop up with a connection tab etc. However when I double tap the file, nothing happens.

**Tried:**

Redownloading and re-checking the files and updating xcode from the previous version to the current version. What seems to be causing the problem?

**Note:**

When I archive the app it says that no devices are connected with the provisioning profile etc. I don't know if connecting my Iphone will resolve the issue? Is there away around this? Such as using app loader? If that works, how do I use it because it was hard to find resources on the internet.